# Regular Expression to split "/n"

Tags: java, regex

I want to split the /n from my string in Java. For example, I have one String field which has 2 lines space ( /n).  I have to find out lines ( wherever mopre than one lines is coming) and should replace with one line spaces.

```
"This is Test Message  


  thanks
  Zubair
"
```

From the above example, there are more spaces between "This is Test Message" and "thanks". So i want to reduce as only one line instead of 2 lines.How to do that?

Comment: Do you mean \n or /n?  I think \n is the newline delimiter

Comment: yes exactly the same what u mean. \n new line delimeter only

Comment: You can search for \\n which means any newline sequence in a regular expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how to use regex, but you can use a StringTokenizer:

```
String reduceToOneLine(String input){
    // Note that this means both \r and \n are tokens, not that they have to appear together.
    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(input, "\r\n"); 
    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
    while(tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()){
        output.append(tokenizer.nextToken());
    }
    return output.toString();
}
```

This splits the string on line breaks, then adds each line to a new string (the tokenizer treats multiples of its delimiter as one, so you'll be left with just one line break between lines).

Comment: Thanks for your reponse i will try and let u know

Comment: As I understand it, the OP wants to reduce two or more consecutive blank lines to one.  This just gets rid of *all* line breaks.

Answer (score 4):

```
str.replaceAll("(\\r\\n?|\\n){3,}", "$1$1");
```

What this does is replace three or more line terminators (`\r`, `\n` or `\r\n`) with two line terminators so any double blank lines are replaced with a single blank line, if I understand what you want correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your reponse i will try and let u know

Comment: I like the use of the references and explicit quantifier. However this won't work correctly if intermediate lines are blank-but-not-empty.

Comment: @pst True, but no clear definition of "empty" was given. Allowing for lines with white space on them is easily added by putting `\s*` in there.